# Centering image with SVG

Tags: image, svg

I have the following image in my `.svg` file:

```
<image xlink:href="developer.mozilla.png" x="50%" y="50%" height="62" width="71"/>
```

I want it display in the middle of the page, but it seems that the upper left corner is in the middle.  How can I get the center of the image to display in the center of the page?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<image xlink:href="developer.mozilla.png" x="50%" y="50%" height="62" width="71" transform="translate(-35.5,-31)"/>
```

Comment: This is genius, thank you so much for sharing. Saved me when trying to switch colored circles over to circular bitmaps on a fluid layout.

Comment: this doesn't work if the `height` or `width` aren't pixels

Comment: @depperm true, until transform supports units (which it already does in css)

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way...

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <svg x="50%" y="50%" width="258px" height="221px" overflow="visible"> 
    <image x="-129px" y="-110.5px" width="258px" height="221px" xlink:href="http://images2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110303182948/hogwartsrpg/images/9/95/KittenCareCat.png"/>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's a lot of work, but it works.  I'll leave this open for a while and see if anyone can come up with anything easier, but if not, it's yours.

Comment: This pattern works well when you have nested objects and pivot points. Thanks for that!